# Remove character that's next to a number, sum these values when a criteria is met, and get the average by group

Tags: excel, logic, formula

| Team | Aging |
| --- | --- |
| Team A | 4 |
| Team G | 54 |
| Team G | >21 |
| Team A | -2 |
| Team B | 30 |
| Team B | >1 |
| Team C | 8 |
| Team D | 1 |
| Team B | -16 |
| Team E | 11 |
| Team A | -7 |
| Team F | >4 |
| Team F | 7 |

NEED:

| Team | Avg. Aging |
| --- | --- |
| Team A |  |
| Team B |  |
| Team C |  |
| Team D |  |
| Team E |  |
| Team F |  |
| Team G |  |

Logic needed:

SUM values in **Aging** column where **Team** column = Team B.
IF these values have an >, then remove this in order to be able to sum.
Once you have removed > and summed where criteria is meet, then find the average.

Requirements: Need the results to be obtained by a single formula. Can't use find and replace to remove >.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL-H to replace > with nothing. Then create a pivot on your data. Summarize by Average.

[image]

**EDIT**

Since you cannot use replace, then here's an alternative solution. Copy/Paste your distinct Teams into column E (remove dupes).

Formula for Cell F2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$14=E2),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($B$2:$B$14,">",""))) / COUNTIF($A$2:$A$14,E2)
```

This formula is first summing the Aging values for each team, and substituting the greater-than sign with nothing and converting those to numbers. Then it's dividing that sum by a count of rows for each team. Excel has an AverageIf formula, but I'm not sure how to make it work with the Substitute function.

Copy it down, done.

[image]

Comment: I need to be able to get the average aging column all within one formula. I can't use any replace function.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to include these types of requirements. Also, you may want to clarify if the greater-than sign is the only character impacting you, or if there are other signs, too.

Comment: @Sam Updates added. If this solves your question, then please consider marking as an approved answer.